# How to update composite objects atomically in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking

I have a simple object that contains other objects modeled like an ordinary 1-many relationship with two tables in SQL server.

Container table

```
 Id  Name
 1   MyContainer
```

Item table

```
 Id ContainerId  Data
 1     1         'A'
 2     1         'B'
```

I want this container object to be always updated atomically. Now imagine there are two operations that will start at the same time:

1. Add an item 3 to container with data 'C'
2. Update two existing items so that data becomes 'AA', 'BB'

I don't want to allow a situation when both operation will "mix" (so that there will be 3 items with 'AA', 'BB', 'C').

I don't think that ordinary transaction will be enough here since operation 2 can first read that there are only 2 items to update, then first one will commit, and then operation 2 will proceed with the update (ideally it should wait until first one fully completes, and then read that there are 3 items and delete the last one).

In other words I want to achieve an "atomic" container update as if it would be a document database having just one document per my "container".

I think I can achieve that with `sp_getapplock`, but this does not seem like a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with an INSTEAD OF trigger on the Item table, and only perform INSERTs.  Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Item_LastWins
ON Item INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Item 
    WHERE Container IN (SELECT Container FROM inserted);

    INSERT INTO Item (Container, Data)
    SELECT Container, Data FROM inserted;
END
```

I assumed that Id was an IDENTITY column; if it's not, you'd have to include that in the INSERT inside the trigger as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i'd rather not delete items though, but rather update them to maintain Id's (as they are identity). But it's possible with your solution just a bit more logic required